# Could not find the "DouglasPeuckerEpsilon" in R language

Tags: r, simplify, douglas-peucker

I'm trying to use Douglas Peucker's algorithm in R.
By executing the following code, I get the following error:

```
Px <- (1:100)/10
Py <- dnorm(Px,3,1)+dnorm(Px,7,1)+Px/10

### Example 1
### Simplification using epsilon

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(Px,Py,type="l")
plot(DouglasPeuckerEpsilon(Px,Py,0.01),type="b",col=4)
Could not find the "DouglasPeuckerEpsilon" in R language.
```

This is because I do not have the DP package installed?

Comment: `DouglasPeuckerEpsilon` appears to come at least from `kmlShape` package. Install that and see if it works for you.

Comment: When I need a function but don't know the package (and it isn't installed on my local R), I'll often google `cran <functionname>`. Searching for `R <functionname>` is just too difficult, but `cran` often provides great hints. In this case (`cran DouglasPeuckerEpsilon`), `kmlShape` as Roman identified is near the top of the list.

Comment: I installed the package 
    `kmlShape` `install.packages("kmlShape")`, and I proceed to execute the statement: 
`plot(DouglasPeuckerEpsilon(Px, Py, 0.04), type = "b", col = 3)`.

And I still get the error:
`Error in plot(DouglasPeuckerEpsilon (Px, Py, 0.04), type = "b", col = 3);
Could not find the "DouglasPeuckerEpsilon"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform the following Steps:

1. Install the package (kmlShape)
2. Then load the Library (kmlShape)

   ```
   install.packages("kmlShape")

   library("kmlShape")
   ```

Then run `plot(DouglasPeuckerEpsilon(Px,Py,0.01),type="b",col=4)` for Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm (RDP)

Comment: @LizandroLuzonM - I'm glad this helped you, Sometimes we tend to skip package load step after installing the package and we wonder what's wrong with the code or package :) !...